# When jaggery / sugar syrup mix is rolled on to sheets, what kind of sheets would be most suitable - least sticky?

Tags: syrup, non-stick, parchment

When jaggery / sugar syrup mix is rolled on to sheets, what kind of sheets would be most suitable - least sticky?

The recipe: [Black Til Chikki](https://cookpad.com/in/recipes/4042926-black-til-chikki)

What kind of non sticky sheets and paper would be most suitable for making such dishes with sticky jaggery or sugar syrups?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use **any typical type of parchment paper**, and to be safe, you can brush the sheet with oil before pouring on the syrup. As parchment paper is already meant to be non-stick, I don't see any problem with the regular kind.

If, by any means, your hardened syrup gets stuck onto the parchment paper, you can place the syrup parchment paper-side down on a warm damp towel for a few minutes, and it should loosen the parchment paper.

Comment: How is it different from Baking paper? I read some about it

Answer (score 0):

Cling-film (US term Saran-wrap, I think)

Since they changed to formular for 'health' reasons in the 90s, basically it only just sticks to itself & barely notices any other substance exists. (Yes, I'm being a tad cynical;)

You just need it stretched out onto something flat & firm (baking tray, chopping board etc - wrap it underneath & try to make it stick to itself a bit - then whatever you put on top of it will be easy to release once it's set.

Comment: I'd do a small test with this first. Most plastic wrap I've used can't withstand much heat.